# Do I need batched parallel programming?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I'm writing a raytracer with EM-processing (radar application). The following is done for many different simulation locations of the radar:

1. raytracing, generates a lot of data
2. EM-postprocessing, generates a scalar and then deletes the raytrace data

Each simulation point will be encapsulated in its own instance of a class (all grouped in a `std::vector`) with a specification of the radar location for that simulation point, references to data it will only read (shared by all simulation points), and properties for storing its results (so each simulation point has its own). Because of this setup I thought I could benefit of using a `for_each` loop with `std::execution::par_unseq` policy without taking further measures. Correct?

The problem however is that the raytracing generates so much data that, when for example having 10 thousand simulation locations, I may run out of memory when the scheduler decides to do all the raytracing first because it is allowed to do so with `par_unseq`. So my idea was to write a normal `for` loop which feeds an inner parallel `for_each` loop with, say, 100 simulation points at the time. Is this an optimal solution for my case? Or did I totally misinterpret how parallel things work?

Comment: A dummy sample code snippet will probably illustrate the problem better than a wall of text. When you need fine-grained control of threading, you schedule it manually. You might also benefit from something like a message queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the standard, `§25.3.3/8`, one can find (emphasis mine):

> The semantics of invocation with `execution​::​unsequenced_­policy`, `execution​::​parallel_­policy`, or `execution​::​parallel_­unsequenced_­policy` allow the implementation **to fall back to sequential execution if the system cannot parallelize an algorithm invocation, e.g., due to lack of resources**.

So implementations are allowed by the standards to fall back to sequential execution if they hit a resource hog.

Comment: Would falling back to sequential processing not be a very significant penalty and would you be better of if you can prevent this on your own? I would think that if the batches are much larger than the number of cores then the additional penalty is very limited but you always keep resources on the safe side.

Comment: @JeroenBoschma Two things. Falling back to sequential processing will possibly result in a significant penalty, but then you don't have the choice if you run out of memory, do you? And secondly, while you could possibly come up with your own way to mitigate that manually, it would have to compete safety- and performance-wise with the standard library implementation you're using. Let's say my bet would be on the team that implemented that library. If you implement it anyway, I encourage you to measure and compare both approach. Safety is another concern that's harder to evaluate at a glance.